# Did I roll this character correctly?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation

Trying to learn some of the basics to Pathfinder with a view to GMing eventually. This is the first time I have rolled a character - have I missed anything? Is this a legal build? (Not optimized, book legal.)

Hoth - Half Elf Sorcerer

Fey bloodline

STR: 10 
DEX: 10 
CON: 15 
INT: 12 
WIS: 11 
CHA: 18 (added +2 for racial bonus)

Favoured classes = Sorcerer and Cleric

Starts with 3 skill points - Heal, Intimidate, and Use Magic Device

Starts with the following spells:

- Resistance
- Detect Magic
- Light
- Daze
- Summon Monster I
- Magic Missile

Starts with Feats:

- Spell Focus
- Eschew Materials (bonus)

Starts with 100GP. Spent 5GP on a dagger, backpack and a set of traveler's clothes.

Answer (score 9):

I will not speak to optimizations since I don't think that's what you're asking.
Legally, it looks fine with one or two possible exceptions.

You forgot that half-elves get Skill focus as a bonus feat at level 1, and you did not define the school for Spell Focus().

You did not list your starting HP. Whenever you gain a level in one of your chosen favored classes you gain either a skill point or a hit point. From my calculations, it looks like you did not take the skill point, but you should include your max HP for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have your hit points and skills calculated out so the answer is "maybe."

- Are the stats rolled or point buy, and if so which value? It's legal for a 20 point buy.
- I'm assuming you put your favored class bonus into hit points (since otherwise you'd have 4 skill points.
- You forgot the half-elf bonus feat skill focus, but you'll need to pick a skill to apply it to.
- You get a set of clothes free at start.

Here's the relevant full stat block from Hero Lab with me making arbitrary choices for alignment (CG, because that's elfy), skill focus (UMD, because it has hard DCs), and spell focus (enchantment, because that stacks with your other stuff):

> **Hoth**
>   Half-Elf Sorcerer 1
>   CG Medium humanoid (elf, human)
>   **Init** +0; **Senses** low-light vision; Perception +2
>
> ---
>
> **Defense**
>
> ---
>
> **AC** 10, touch 10, flat-footed 10
>   **hp** 9 (1d6+3)
>   **Fort** +2, **Ref** +0, **Will** +2; +2 vs. enchantments
>   **Immune** sleep
>
> ---
>
> **Offense**
>
> ---
>
> **Speed** 30 ft.
>   **Melee** dagger +0 (1d4/19-20)
>   **Special Attacks** bloodline arcana: fey
>   **Spell-Like Abilities** (CL 1st; concentration +5)
>      7/day—*laughing touch*
>   **Sorcerer Spells Known** (CL 1st; concentration +5):
>      1st (4/day)—*magic missile, summon monster i*
>      0 (at will)—*daze (DC 17), detect magic, light, resistance*
>
> ---
>
> **Statistics**
>
> ---
>
> **Str** 10, **Dex** 10, **Con** 15, **Int** 12, **Wis** 11, **Cha** 18
>   **Base Atk** +0; **CMB** +0; **CMD** 10
>   **Feats** Eschew Materials, Skill Focus (Use Magic Device), Spell Focus (enchantment)
>   **Skills** Heal +1, Intimidate +8, Perception +2, Use Magic Device +11; **Racial Modifiers** +2 Perception
>   **Languages** Common, Elven, Sylvan
>   **SQ** bloodlines (fey), elf blood
>   **Other Gear** dagger, backpack, 96 gp
>
> ---
>
> **Special Abilities**
>
> ---
>
> **Bloodline Arcana: Fey (Ex)** +2 to save DCs from spells of the Compulsion subschool.
>   **Elf Blood** Half-elves count as both elves and humans for any effect related to race.
>   **Elven Immunities - Sleep** You are immune to magic sleep effects.
>   **Eschew Materials** Cast spells without materials, if component cost is 1 gp or less.
>   **Fey** +2 to save DCs from spells of the Compulsion subschool.
>   **Laughing Touch (7/day) (Su)** Melee touch attack leaves target able to take only move actions.
>   **Low-Light Vision** See twice as far as a human in low light, distinguishing color and detail.
>   **Spell Focus (Enchantment)** Spells from one school of magic have +1 to their save DC.